# How to Draw ellipses with an interval into PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I want to make a simple simulation using ellipses. In user interface, there will be a button. User will press the button, then with 1 second interval, ellipses will be drawn to pictureBox. Like a traffic light...

I guess I need to use Timer Event, but Don't know how to.
How can I achieve it?

My best regards...

**CodeWork**:

```
public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DrawMap ortamcizdir = new DrawMap(p_box_map, bmp, ZoomControl, panel1);
   DrawCell hucrecizdir = new DrawCell (p_box_map, bmp, a, ZoomControl, ZoomKontrolBolen);
}

class DrawCell
{
   for (int z = 0; z < Ortamlar.HucreSayisi; z++)
   {
         Pen Kalem = new Pen(Brushes.CadetBlue);
         Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(((Ortamlar.HUCREKorX[z] / ScaleFactor - Ortamlar.HUCREYaricap[z] / ScaleFactor)
                        * ZoomKontrolCarpan) / ZoomKontrolBolen, (Ortamlar.HUCREKorY[z] / ScaleFactor - Ortamlar.HUCREYaricap[z] / ScaleFactor) *
                        ZoomKontrolCarpan / ZoomKontrolBolen, (2 * Ortamlar.HUCREYaricap[z] / ScaleFactor) * ZoomKontrolCarpan / ZoomKontrolBolen
                        , (2 * Ortamlar.HUCREYaricap[z] / ScaleFactor) * ZoomKontrolCarpan / ZoomKontrolBolen);

         if (Ortamlar.HUCREYZ[z] == "001:400")
         {
                g.DrawString(Ortamlar.HUCREKB[z].ToString(), Font, Brushes.Black, ((Ortamlar.HUCREKorX[z] / ScaleFactor)
                    * ZoomKontrolCarpan) / ZoomKontrolBolen, 600 - (Ortamlar.HUCREKorY[z] / ScaleFactor) *
                    ZoomKontrolCarpan / ZoomKontrolBolen);
                g.MultiplyTransform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 600));
                g.DrawEllipse(Kalem, rect);

                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Wheat, rect);
                g.ResetTransform();

                picturebox1.Image = bmp;
                bmp1 = (Bitmap)picturebox1.Image;
          }
          if (Ortamlar.HUCREYZ[z] == "401:800")
          {
                        g.DrawString(Ortamlar.HUCREKB[z].ToString(), Font, Brushes.Black, ((Ortamlar.HUCREKorX[z] / ScaleFactor)
                    * ZoomKontrolCarpan) / ZoomKontrolBolen, 600 - (Ortamlar.HUCREKorY[z] / ScaleFactor) *
                    ZoomKontrolCarpan / ZoomKontrolBolen);
                        g.MultiplyTransform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 600));
                        g.DrawEllipse(Kalem, rect);

                        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, rect);

                        g.ResetTransform();
                        picturebox1.Image = bmp;
                        bmp2 = (Bitmap)picturebox1.Image;
          }
          if (Ortamlar.HUCREYZ[z] == "801:120")
          {
                        g.DrawString(Ortamlar.HUCREKB[z].ToString(), Font, Brushes.Black, ((Ortamlar.HUCREKorX[z] / ScaleFactor)
                    * ZoomKontrolCarpan) / ZoomKontrolBolen, 600 - (Ortamlar.HUCREKorY[z] / ScaleFactor) *
                    ZoomKontrolCarpan / ZoomKontrolBolen);
                        g.MultiplyTransform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 600));
                        g.DrawEllipse(Kalem, rect);

                        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, rect);
                        g.ResetTransform();

                        picturebox1.Image = bmp;
                        bmp3 = (Bitmap)picturebox1.Image;
          }
          if (Ortamlar.HUCREYZ[z] == "121:161")
          {
                        g.DrawString(Ortamlar.HUCREKB[z].ToString(), Font, Brushes.Black, ((Ortamlar.HUCREKorX[z] / ScaleFactor)
                    * ZoomKontrolCarpan) / ZoomKontrolBolen, 600 - (Ortamlar.HUCREKorY[z] / ScaleFactor) *
                        ZoomKontrolCarpan / ZoomKontrolBolen);
                        g.MultiplyTransform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 600));
                        g.DrawEllipse(Kalem, rect);

                        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, rect);

                        g.ResetTransform();
                        picturebox1.Image = bmp;
                        bmp4 = (Bitmap)picturebox1.Image;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want us to write the code for you? Pass.

Comment: @Cody Gray I just need any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont quite understand the purpose of what you're asking, but im guessing you can get close by reading through these links.

The [first](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer) will run you through most of what you need to know about the timer control.

The [second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will let you in on ways to draw the ellipses.

About how to structure your code, well simply put, i'd get the button to start the timer, then the timerElapsed event would control the creation of ellipses in the picture box, every 1second.

For more explanations, i think it would be best if you put some code together so we can understand better what your intentions are. Then we might be able to help out more. Hope this helps though.

**[edit1]**

This will create ellipses untill the timer stops, you can add a button to stop timer1:

```
public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawMap ortamcizdir = new DrawMap(p_box_map, bmp, ZoomControl, panel1);
    DrawCell hucrecizdir = new DrawCell (p_box_map, bmp, a, ZoomControl, ZoomKontrolBolen);
}
```

Dont forget you need to drag the timer onto the design, then double-click the **Tick** event on the *property pane*.

This answer considers that nothing is wrong with the DrawCell class.

**[edit2]**

I was thinking about what i posted and this would create ellipses untill the timer stops. So you might want to add a `while` statement to control how many ellipses to draw. Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) to see other ways to implement that.

This way you can set the amount of ellipses to draw, this is an example, but there are plenty ways to pull it off.

```
//create this field and property before the constructor
public int counter;
public int Counter
{
    get { return counter; }
    set { counter = value; }
}

//button click sets the interval to 1sec, starts timer and sets the int Counter to 0
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
    Counter = 0;
}

//the tick event iterates the Counter property +1 everytime the timer advances 1sec and while Counter is under 5 for example it creates those objects
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Counter++;
    while (counter < 5)
    {
        DrawMap ortamcizdir = new DrawMap(p_box_map, bmp, ZoomControl, panel1);
        DrawCell hucrecizdir = new DrawCell (p_box_map, bmp, a, ZoomControl, ZoomKontrolBolen);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend, I have 2 classes That draws a Map and ellipses onto the map, respectively. But According to some constraints, there color is different. What I want to make is to draw those ellipses one by one with 1 second intervals.

Comment: Im guessing you can place the `CreateEllipse();` method into the timer event `Tick`. You just need to set `timer1.Interval = 1000;` Try updating your question with some code so we can help more. How have you tried to do it?

Comment: I will try what you said and let you know, Thank you... I guess I'm making mistake using Tick event...